# C# data binding nested ItemsControl wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

I want to build a UserInterface like this (a timeline for a video editor)
[image]

and I have all classes:

```
public class Timeline
    {
        public Timeline()
        {
            groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Group> groups { get; set; }

    }

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TrackGroup()
    {
        tracks = new List<Track>();
    }

    public List<Track> tracks { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public Track()
    {
        units= new ObservableCollection<Unit>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Unit> units { get; set; }
}

public class Unit
{
    public string unitName { get; set; }
}
```

And in Main I have this:

```
public Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
public Unit unit = new Unit();
public Track track = new Track();
public Group group = new Group();
track.units.Add(unit);
group.tracks.Add(track);
timeline.groups.Add(group);
```

And in Main.xaml(not complete because it doesn't work)

```
<ListBox
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding timeline.groups}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding timeline.groups.tracks}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding timeline.groups.tracks.units}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

How can I binding each itemssource? because **timeline**, **group**, **track** all are list, so I need to show them in ItemsControl. I was very confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use 'full' path for bindings at inner lists.

Because when you bind some `ItemControl` and try to style it's item remember that each item already an example of collection that you used as `ItemsSource`

**Edit1:**

 Window.xaml.cs file:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
Unit unit1 = new Unit() {unitName = "1"};
Unit unit2 = new Unit() {unitName = "2"};
Track track = new Track();
Group group = new Group();
track.units.Add(unit1);
track.units.Add(unit2);
group.tracks.Add(track);
timeline.groups.Add(group);
list.DataContext = timeline;
```

here i didn't use VM if you want to use VM just add it to data context of your window and bind list to it.
Xaml:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             Name="list"
             ItemsSource="{Binding groups}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding tracks}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding units}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding unitName}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Just style, tested it. If you'll use VM with `Timeline` property change binding to 'timelinePropertyName'.groups

And read more about bindings.

Comment: It doesn't work from "binding timeline.groups". I use "datacontext = this" in main class, is it right?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try capitalizing the appropriate members. WPF is case sensitive.